# How to keep sprites position after Unity animation?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I just recently began using Unity3D and this is my first game, so if I'm not doing things like I'm supposed to, please tell me.

There is a 2D character that I want to move one step forward using the Animation mechanism. This movement can be splitted in two parts :

- Move forward the back leg, don't move the upper body ;
- Use this leg to push and make the step, moving the upper body.

[image]

My problème is that I can't find a way to make this step permanent. As soon as it start looping on the "Idle" animation, then, it come back to the original position (before the step).

[image]

I don't know how to let my character stay in the position it was just between the "Step Forward" animation and the "Idle" animation.

I tried to add "Rigidbody 2D", "Box Collider 2D" and "Physics2D Material" on both feet and on the floor, but it somewhat breaks the IK script ("Simple CCD", from the youtube video "Unite 2014 - 2D Best Practices In Unity"). And I'm sure there is a much simpler way.

EDIT: My question was not clear enough. The idle animation is the default animation, where the character is doing nothing in particular. It's just moving a little while it's staying in position. When it runs "Step Forward", all the sprites are moved (only when the back leg is pushing). If all animations are stopped right now, then the character is indeed in a new position, closer to it's opponent. I can check that by removing the transition from "Step Forward" to "Idle". But from here, I want it to loop on the Idle animation. When the transition from "Step forward" to "Idle" is done, the character is NOT running Idle from it's new position, but from it's old position, before the step, as if it was pulled from backward. I want to run Idle from the new position.

Here is a longer gif when we can see more of the Idle animation :

[image]

And my Hierarchy panel looks like :

- Main Camera
- Karateka (the top GameObject container, with the `Animator` component)

  - Torso (the sprites)

    - Head
    - Right arm
    - Right leg

      - Right lower leg

        - Right foot
    - ...
  - IK (the Inverse Kinematics targets)

    - Left fist target
    - Left foot target
    - ...

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: I think you haven't tried Root animation. I'm guessing that is what you're looking for as When you stepForward, it won't return back to initial transform. If you change transform via animation then the character's actual Transform will also change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get it right, you have the StepForward animation running and it gets cut in the middle back to idle. There, the StepForward animation triggers again but from the start and you wish to restart from where you left off:

You can record the normalized value of your StepForward animation and use it next time:

```
   float normValue = this.animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime;
```

then you can use that value:

```
 this.animator.Play("StepForward", 0, normValue);
```

Other possibility, you are not after that but simply you want to pause the animation without getting to Idle.

Use a parameter. You can add a float parameter (call it direction) in the Animator window (top left). Then select a state in the animator, it will open the animation setting in the inspector. Under speed, open the drop down where your new parameter should show up. And tick it.

Now, your direction float will affect the speed of your animation as such:

```
this.animator.SetFloat("direction", value);
```

if you give 0, you pause. Give back 1 to move forward. You can also lerp the value so it is not abrupt. Your way.

Comment: Well, I guess, I was not very clear, sorry. Idle animation is running fine, then, I run StepForward and the character move forward as expected. If I remove the back transition to Idle, the character stay in its new position. Now from its new position, I want it to loop on Idle animation. But if I keep the transition from StepForward to Idle, my character is moved back to its old position, before the StepForward animation. I didn't know about the GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo and it will probably get handy later, thank you for that. I'm going to edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Could it be that the StepForward animation affects the top object position? Lets say the anim should move the object from 0 to 1, if it us on the top object, unity will place it at 0 wherever it is. Now if you add one parent object and affect what gas become the first child, it eill move from 0 to 1 in the parent space (local space). Then wherever the parent is, it will set at 0 in rhe oarent world, not the entire world.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. I have a GameObject containing bot the sprites (the upper torso is at the top of the hierarchy) and the IK targets. If I only move the sprites and the IK targets, my top GameObject is not moved. At the end of the "Step forward" animation, I will try to get the distance between the start and the end of the move, then shift the top GameObject in one side and the contained GameObject on the other side.

Comment: It looks like I still don't understand. On my last keyframe, I translated the top GameObject and the IK targets, then I reset the Torso GameObject to 0, but it doesn't change a thing on the pulling effect at the end. I tested a translation from code , with `transform.localPosition.x`, it didn't move the way I intended, but it moved (I moved it at the start of the step, after setting my trigger for the animation.). I think I can work something from here, but it looks like a terrible solution. I think there is a much simpler way of doing it. There must be something I don't get right.

Comment: Generally, with animation, the top object contains the Animator but it controls only sub objects (not always). The top object is controlled by script for movement and others. The problem with animation is that it does not do (current + animation movement) it just takes what is the value on the animation and applies it. Your animation should only consider the values for the sub objects and the top one is controlled by another script. That script may move the object along with the animation.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand much better what I have to do. I will accept your answer, thank you.